# How to have a custom element be defined on npm install

Tags: javascript, npm, custom-element

I wanted to try and use a custom web component I made using vanilla javascript with npm. So I published it to npm to import it into another learning thing I am working on. My problem was that my environment didn't recognize the custom element.

My package.json defined main to be the 'index.js' file. The file defined the component using the standard customElements.define. This element didn't seem to be registered when I wanted to use it.

My current hack workaround is

```js
class CustomElement { ... }
function defineCustomElement() { 
  customElements.define('tag-name', CustomElement)
}
export default defineCustomElement
```

This feels like a horrible hack though. When I search around, I don't see my problem mentioned and I can't manage to find any good information, so I'm probably missing something on what I should be searching for/looking at.

My goal would be that by just defining the component as a dependency in package.json it would automatically be defined.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Answering your goal first: No, it will not be automatically defined. By adding this to a package.json you will just add it as a project dependency (just will be added in the node_modules/ folder after the install) and no action will be done. You would have to do more to add this in another project, like importing it and call the function to register the custom element in the desired web project.

Also, worth notice that your export it's just exporting the defineCustomElement function and not calling it!

Comment: @LeonardoFachiniMartins Is it possible to write the export code in such a way that it would get automatically defined? I am aware that I am currently just exporting a function without calling it.

Comment: ditch npm (for now) and first learn to work with Custom Elements in a JSFiddle or CodePen; you are trying to run before you can walk

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman The component works. That is not the issue.

Comment: @Agryphos it's not possible to write an export code as you're picturing it. You would have to export it, import in some place and bootstrap it in your code. You can choose several ways to do this, but none of them is just export and start using right away.